# Rearranging parsed HTML data in Python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have little experience programming so please excuse my ignorance.

I'm trying to parse the 'Key Statistics' page from Yahoo! Finance, to be specific [this](http://finance.yahoo.com/q/ks?s=JPM+Key+Statistics) page. I've been fooling around with BeautifulSoup and was able to extract the data I wanted but have since ran into a mental block. I would like the data to appear like this:

```
measure[i]: value[i]
.
.  
measure[n]: value[n]
```

but the results I'm getting with my script is:

```
measure[i]  
.
.    
measure[n]  
value[i]
.
.
value[n]
```

Here is my attempt of joining the two data fields together which throws an error:

```
measure = soup.findAll('td', {'class':'yfnc_tablehead1'}, width='74%')  
value = soup.findAll('td', {'class':'yfnc_tabledata1'}) 

for incident in measure:
    x = incident.contents

for incident2 in value:
    y = incident2.contents

data = x + y

print ': '.join(data)
```

Moreover there are unwanted characters in these values I would like to remove but I will read up on the re.compile and re.sub documentation.

Thank you for any input.

Answer (score 2):

```
data = x + y
```

the `+` operator appends lists, if you want to couple corresponding items of the lists try the `zip()` function:

```
data = zip(x,y)
for m,v in data:
  print m,v
```

also,

```
for incident in measure:
  x = incident.contents
```

this overwrites `x` in every iteration of the loop so in the end `x` contains only the last value assigned and not the aggregate of them all. here you probably do want to use the `+` operator like so:

```
for incident in measure:
  x += incident.contents # x += y is the same as x = x + y
```

of course the same goes for the other loop.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Your method actually eliminated the need for me to go in and remove unwanted tags, but like you mentioned, only the last value was displayed. What (efficient) approach would you suggest to replace the 'for' loop I've implemented to display an aggregate of all values?

Comment: please disregard that comment! I eliminated the for loops and implemented your suggestion. Now all that is left to do is to go in with BeautifulSoup and clean up unwanted tags.

Answer (score 0):

```
measures = ['1', '2', '3', '4']
values = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']

for pair in zip(measures, values):
    print ': '.join(pair)

# 1: a
# 2: b
# 3: c
# 4: d
```

About `zip` :

```
Type:       builtin_function_or_method
Base Class: <type 'builtin_function_or_method'>
String Form:<built-in function zip>
Namespace:  Python builtin
Docstring:
zip(seq1 [, seq2 [...]]) -> [(seq1[0], seq2[0] ...), (...)]

Return a list of tuples, where each tuple contains the i-th element
from each of the argument sequences.  The returned list is truncated
in length to the length of the shortest argument sequence.
```